# Where is HQL clearly defined?

Tags: sql, hibernate

My IDE is using a different SQL syntax than I am familiar with for hibernate queries. I go to the HQL docs ( http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html ) and they don't explain how this query is derived. It's simple and there has to be a syntax definition for what I'm finding but I can't find it. Can someone elucidate me?

A basic HQL query reads like this:

```
SELECT u FROM User u
```

In SQL I would write this like this:

```
SELECT * FROM User;
```

or

```
SELECT u.* FROM User AS u;
```

But who needs the extra complexity for such a simple query.

Where is HQL defined clearly?

Comment: Huh? You linked to the docs which define HQL. The main difference is indicated in the first paragraph of that link: the extra complexity stems from it being a mapping between object and tables, ie "HQL is fully object-oriented and understands notions like inheritance, polymorphism and association"

Comment: Bizmark, The docs I linked to do not define the simple query example I gave.

Comment: Specifically section 14.6 of the JBOSS link above defines the SELECT clause but does *not* use a generic select clause and does not explain the use of the synonym "u" in place of the asterisk to select the entire column list or the absence of the "as" in defining the synonym in "user u".  Or, I'm completely mis interpreting the HQL because there are no good docs for it.  Could "u" be a reference to the "User.Java" class that defines the same columns as the User table in the DB or vice versa...  If so, I don't see this mapping anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You have to think of it differently, it's like running SQL queries against Java objects, hence it's hybrid nature. You wouldn't write `SELECT u From User u` in HQL, you could simply write `from yourPackage.User` and that will retrieve all instances of the `User` class, ie. all the objects which map to rows in the DB.

The `select` clause in HQL is more for accessing individual properties in the class instances, for example `select u.name from User u` will get a list of all `name`s, which are properties in the Java objects mapped to the table.